# Why `floorEntry` and other methods are not accessible in PatriciaTrie?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, apache-commons-collection, patricia-trie

While implementing an ip-lookup structure, I was trying to maintain a set of keys in a trie-like structure that allows me to search the "floor" of a key (that is, the largest key that is less or equal to a given key). I decided to use Apache Collections 4 [PatriciaTrie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html) but sadly, I found that the [floorEntry](https://github.com/apache/commons-collections/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/AbstractPatriciaTrie.java#L1041) and related methods are not `public`. My current "dirty" solution is forcing them with reflection (in Scala):

```
val pt = new PatriciaTrie[String]()
val method = pt.getClass.getSuperclass.getDeclaredMethod("floorEntry", classOf[Object])
method.setAccessible(true)
// and then for retrieving the entry for floor(key) 
val entry = method.invoke(pt, key).asInstanceOf[Entry[String, String]]
```

Is there any clean way to have the same functionality? Why this methods are not publicly available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why those methods are not public, I don't know. (Maybe it's because you can achieve what you want with common `Map` API).

Here's a way to fulfil your requirement:

```
PatriciaTrie<String> trie = new PatriciaTrie<>();
trie.put("a", "a");
trie.put("b", "b");
trie.put("d", "d");

String floorKey = trie.headMap("d").lastKey(); // d
```

According to the docs, this is very efficient, since it depends on the number of bits of the largest key of the trie.

**EDIT:** As per the comment below, the code above has a bounds issue: `headMap()` returns a view of the map whose keys are *strictly* lower than the given key. This means that, i.e. for the above example, `trie.headMap("b").lastKey()` will return `"a"`, instead of `"b"` (as needed).

In order to fix this bounds issue, you can use the following trick:

```
String cFloorKey = trie.headMap("c" + "\uefff").lastKey(); // b

String dFloorKey = trie.headMap("d" + "\uefff").lastKey(); // d
```

Now everything works as expected, since `\uefff` is the highest unicode character. Actually, searching for `key + "\uefff"`, whatever `key` is, will always return `key` if it belongs to the trie, or the element immediately prior to `key`, if `key` is not present in the trie.

Now, this trick works for `String` keys, but is extensible to other types as well. i.e. for `Integer` keys you could search for `key + 1`, for `Date` keys you could add 1 millisecond, etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `trie.headMap(k).lastKey();` won't return `k` if it's already contained in the map, since the doc for `headMap` says that it *"Returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys are strictly less than toKey"*.